# Left aligning image on centered UIButton

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton

What is a good way to have the image edge insets of a UIButton be left aligned while having the title completely centered?  Such as the following:

[image]

The image would have a constant left inset, but the title would always be centered in the entire button. Most solutions that I have found date back 4 or 5 years, and they are based on manually calculating the necessary inset of the image while keeping a center alignment for the title.

Are there really no easy ways of doing this yet?

Comment: Using constraints should do the job right? Set `Leading` to zero for the asset, and set the title center-aligned horizontally.

Comment: I assume that you mean to put the asset there as a subview to the button? Because I don't think using UIButton's built in image property lets you edit any constraints

Comment: yea. alternatively do left alignment for control alignment for the button and a UILabel additionally for the title

Comment: Solution 1: Subclass UIButton and override `- (CGRect)titleRectForContentRect:(CGRect)contentRect` and `- (CGRect)imageRectForContentRect:(CGRect)contentRect` method. Solution2 : Modify `titleEdgeInsets` and `imageEdgeInsets` property of `UIButton`.

Answer (score 0):

You can set asset left aligned by using an image for your button and set horizontal alignment to left. For the title, you could add an additional UILabel and constraint it in a horizontal center-aligned manner.

[image: button with asset left aligned]
[image: set horizontal alignment]

Comment: Thank you for the input. I am aware that I can achieve this by using subviews, but I would rather not. It makes things like button states suddenly become a pain in the ****.

Comment: The concern about button states is indeed a valid argument. Then you might want to try to use two buttons in a UIView container. One button is for the asset, one for the title. And constraint them according to your requirement.

Answer (score 0):

you can set edge to change position of text and image of button

[image]

set Left Top Bottom and right according your requirement.